# Android Universe library showImageOnLoading issue

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I have some issues with DisplayImageOptions.Builder()**.showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)**

> The method showImageOnLoading(int) is undefined for the type
>   DisplayImageOptions.Builder

Other options, like:

```
 .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub)
 .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
 .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
```

are valid and work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`showImageOnLoading(...)` will be available in next lib version. This is replacement for `showStubImage(...)` which does exactly the same.

Comment: How do you build the sample with the older library?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the version of the library, [Use this version of the library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/sample/libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.7-snapshot-with-sources.jar),I worked..